# IBM X Storage X3650m3 for SGDEVODB02

Tags: configuration, storage

Error showing some of the monitored parameters are abnormal in my IBM storage X3650m3 but it showing green color so i dont know whats the problem here? Can any one please help?

Update:

In IBM Integrated Management Module storage X3650m3 GUI console, at system status -> System Health Summary -> It showing "Some of the monitored parameters are abnormal".

```
Critical Events
Array in system "Host" is in critical condition
Array in system "Host" is in critical condition
Array in system "Host" is in critical condition
Array in system "Host" has failed
```

There is no error logs in event logs and also it shows green light in server. So I want to know the above error is problem or its just an bug?

[Image of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaWVf.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SF. You'll need to provide much more detail for people to be able to help: which parameters are abnormal? Can you provide log output or screenshots?

Comment: In IBM Integrated Management Module storage X3650m3 GUI console, at system status -> System Health Summary -> It showing "Some of the monitored parameters are abnormal" .

Critical Events
    
Array in system "Host" is in critical condition
Array in system "Host" is in critical condition
Array in system "Host" is in critical condition
Array in system "Host" has failed

There is no error logs in event logs and also it shows green light in server. So I want to know the above error is problem or its just an bug?

Comment: Anyone please answer my above question will be very helpfull..